# Pokedex dictionary, how i can add methods into a dictionary?

Tags: c#, dictionary, collections

i have a problem with collections... specific with dictionaries ...
I wanted to create a pokedex (need some coding excercises) and now i want to add the pokemon with the methods in a dictionary... so i can search a pokemon by 1. name 2. type and 3. devStages...

for example:
if i want to search for "reptain" in the type categorie ... it should give me out the reptain type description (this is a method inside the Pokemon class)

pokemon class:

```
public class Pokemon
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int NumberDevStages { get; set; }
    public string PokémonType { get; set; }
    public string PreviousStages { get; set; }
    public string FollowingStages { get; set; }


    public Pokemon(string _name, int _numberDevStages, string _pokemonType, string _previousStages, string _followingStages)
    {
        Name = _name;
        NumberDevStages = _numberDevStages;
        PokémonType = _pokemonType;
        PreviousStages = _previousStages;
        FollowingStages = _followingStages;
    }


    public void AllInfos()
    {
        PokémonDescriptionM();
        NumberDevStagesM();
        PreviousStagesM();
        FollowingStagesM();

    }


    public void PokémonDescriptionM()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{Name} is a {PokémonType} pokemon.");
    }

    public void NumberDevStagesM()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{Name} has {NumberDevStages} stages of development");
    }

    public void PreviousStagesM()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"The previous stages of {Name} are: {PreviousStages}");
    }

    public void FollowingStagesM()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"The following stages of {Name} are: {FollowingStages} .");
    }
```

and the programm:

```
class Program
{
    //Pokédex! 
    //Filter-function = type, development stages, name

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Pokemon reptain = new Pokemon("Reptain", 3, "plant", "Geckarbor", "(Lvl 36) Gewaldro");
        Pokemon gewaldro = new Pokemon("Gewaldro", 3, "plant", "Reptain & Geckarbor", "Gewaldro is the final form!");

        Pokemon flemmli = new Pokemon("Flemmli", 3, "fire", "Flemmli is the first stage", "(Lvl 16) Jungglut and (Lvl 36) Lohgock");
        Pokemon jungglut = new Pokemon("Jungglut", 3, "fire", "Flemmli", "(Lvl 36) Lohgock");
        Pokemon lohgock = new Pokemon("Lohgock", 3, "fire", "Flemmli & Jungglut", "Lohgock is the final form!");


        Dictionary<Pokemon, Pokemon> pokemonTypeDictonary = new Dictionary<Pokemon, Pokemon>();
        pokemonTypeDictonary.Add(reptain, reptain.PokémonDescriptionM);
        pokemonTypeDictonary.Add(reptain, reptain.PokémonDescriptionM.ToString());  //It doesnt work. How it would work??

        Console.WriteLine(pokemonTypeDictonary[reptain]);



        Welcome:
        //Pokédex welcome
        Welcome();
        AllFilterCategories();

        //Choose categorie
        Console.Write("\nPlease enter the desired filter option as a number (1, 2 or 3)! : ");
        string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
        int userInputINT = TryParseINT(userInput);

        //Select the categorie
        switch(userInputINT)
        {
            case 1:
                NameSearching();
                break;
            case 2:
                TypeSearching();
                break;
            case 3:
                DevStagesSearching();
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("You're entry was not recognized");
                Console.ReadKey();
                Console.Clear();
                goto Welcome;

        }


    }

    private static void Welcome()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n===========================================");
        Console.WriteLine("Hi and a warm welcome to Marco's pokédex!");
        Console.WriteLine("===========================================\n\n");
    }

    private static void AllFilterCategories()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Filter by:\n");
        Console.WriteLine("      1 =  Name");
        Console.WriteLine("      2 =  Type");
        Console.WriteLine("      3 =  Development-Stages");
    }

    private static int TryParseINT(string userInput)
    {
        int tryParseINT;
        while (true)
            if (int.TryParse(userInput, out tryParseINT))
            {
                return tryParseINT;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your entry was not recognized, the program will be closed");
                Console.ReadKey();
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
    }

    private static void NameSearching()
    {
        Console.Write("Ok, you want to search a name. Which name? : ");
        string whichName = Console.ReadLine();
        whichName = whichName.ToUpper();

        if (whichName == "GECKARBOR")
        {
            Pokemon geckarbor = new Pokemon("Geckarbor", 3, "plant", "Geckarbor is the first stage", "(Lvl 16) Reptain and (Lvl 36) Gewaldro");
            Console.WriteLine("\n\n");
            geckarbor.AllInfos();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        else if (whichName == "FLEMMLI")
        {
            Pokemon flemmli = new Pokemon("Flemmli", 3, "fire", "Flemmli is the first stage", "(Lvl 16) Jungglut and (Lvl 36) Lohgock");
            Console.WriteLine("\n\n");
            flemmli.AllInfos();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        
        // ... ... ... 
    }

    private static void TypeSearching()
    {
        Console.Write("Ok, you want to search a type. Which type? : ");
        string whichType = Console.ReadLine();


    }

    private static void DevStagesSearching()
    {
        Console.Write("Ok, you want to search development stages. How many stages? : ");
        string howManyStages = Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void TypeDictionary()
    {

    }
```

I have no idea how clean this code is...
Is it total crap?
Im a beginner and im in a big struggle with my skills at the moment...

Comment: It's a bit unclear for me what exactly you're trying to achieve with the `Dictionary<Pokemon, Pokemon>`. A `Dictionary` is a datastructure that holds key value pairs, providing quick lookups of the value belonging to a provided key. To me it feels like you might instead want to have a `List` of all pokemon and search that list for pokemon matching whatever search criteria you wish. so `var pokemons = new List<Pokemon> { reptain, gewaldro, flemmli, jingglut, lohgock };` and then you can do `var plantPokemon = pokemons.Where(pokemon => pokemon.PokemonType == "plant").ToList();`.

Comment: Thanks! I try this one and will try to understand it! in the first place i thought a dictionary is the right way to collect what i want -> search for a specific Pokemon and then get out the informations .. Search with the key, and then get out the infos with the value

Comment: Yes if you want to be able to get a pokemon for a specific key (like its name) you can create a `Dictionary` for that. In the name example it would look like `var pokemonDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Pokemon>;` and then `pokemonDictionary.Add(reptain.Name, reptain);`. Then you can do something like `var reptainDescription = pokemonDictionary["Reptain"].PokemonDescriptionM();`. Good luck with your project!

Comment: You're welcome! Also for now I wouldn't worry about "clean" code. To me it feels like you're on the right track of learning. Make small exercises and goals for your self, try to get those working and try to understand why and how they work. Once you have a feel for how and why a piece of code works you can start thinking about cleaning up that code. We all had to start somewhere:-)